# Tags "permutation" and "permutations" need to be joined

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

As the title says: we have the tag [permutation](/questions/tagged/permutation), with 200ish questions, and [permutations](/questions/tagged/permutations) with 5. The latter should probably go.

Answer (score 2):

Is this accurate? There's already been a synonym in place for some time ([Michael Myers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13531/michael-myers) made it 7 August), and it indicates no posts remain tagged [permutations](/questions/tagged/permutations)